# Google Analytics: Categorise data based on fields passed as event parameters

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I am trying to implement google analytics for a website and I'm using [this list](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event) of events as a guideline for the events we use on the website.

For example, the `share` event is documented as

> `share` | `method`, `content_type`, `content_id`  | a user shares content

I'm passing the parameters `method`, `content_type`, `content_id` but I can't seem to be able to find a way to pivot on those values in the reports.

TLDR; How do we use the parameters for events as secondary dimensions in event reports? or, even from a custom report from where I can see the number of `share` events across different `content_type`s for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, only the "method" parameter is captured. The content_type and content_id parameters are not captured in GA, even though you've sent it and use Google's Documentation.

I recommend you can do it this way since "Engagement" and "Share" are redundant information to you, you can "float" everything one level up:

```
gtag('event', {content-type}, {
  'event_category': 'share -'+{method},
  'event_label': {content id},
});
```

fill in the variables and you'll be capturing the IDs and content type and id in the action and label dimensions. I think this is the simplest solution before getting into custom dimensions.

Comment: That is so weird. Thanks for confirming that. I find it really weird there is a parameter listed in the docs which you can't access in the dashboard. I'm going to leave this question open hoping someone out there knows some obscure way to do this right... (Why have a parameter which is essentially useless)

Comment: I've added a suggestion. Hopefully it will meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics uses the following categorization (dimensions) for event details:

- Category
- Action
- Label
- And also a Value can be provided optionally

Based on this [support article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events):

> a subset of gtag.js events called Google Analytics Events, events that
>   appear in the Google Analytics Event reports.

The article also describes, how you can send any custom event to Google Analytics:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

It also describes how the default events should be used, e.g. for content sharing, you are trying to track:

```
Event name: share
Default category: engagement
Default label type: method
```

If you need to track additional details, like content type or content id, you can use custom dimensions to store these additional details. (Support article on this topic is available [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets))

In you reports, you should look for Event action and Event label dimensions for a breakdown, or pivot view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I had figured out this much from their docs... It's really weird that they specify it as a parameter but don't make it accessible in the dashboards.